# How to add multiple RestController endpoints differed by query-params?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

How can I simply redirect a url if a specific query parameter is missing?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    //only in case the "sort" query parameter is missing
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public String unsorted() {
         return "redirect:/persons?sort=name";
    }

    //only in case the "sort" query parameter exists
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public String sorted() {
         //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [@GetMapping.params](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#params--)

```
@GetMapping(value = "/persons", params = "sort")
public String sorted() {
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use @RequestParam to extract query parameters
- Add parameter for @RequestParam: value, defaultValue, required

**with java >= 8:**

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
     @GetMapping("/persons")
     public String personList(@RequestParam(value = "sort", defaultValue = "name") Optional<String> sort) {
         //handling process here
     }
}
```

**with java < 8:**

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
     @GetMapping("/persons")
     public String personList(@RequestParam(value = "sort", defaultValue = "name", required=false) String sort) {
         //handling process here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `params` element. One mapping will supports `params="sort"` for when the sort parameter is present and the other `params="!sort"` for when it is missing.

However, you may want to consider using a default value instead of performing a redirect. What benefit does the redirect provide? It will require the server respond and then and have the client make a second HTTP request.

**Using params**

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    //only in case the "sort" query parameter is missing
    @GetMapping(value = "/persons", params = "!sort")
    public String unsorted() {
         return "redirect:/persons?sort=name";
    }

    //only in case the "sort" query parameter exists
    @GetMapping(value = "/persons", params = "sort")
    public String sorted() {
         //...
    }
}
```

**Using default value**

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    //only in case the "sort" query parameter exists
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public String sorted(
        @RequestParam(name = "sort", defaultValue = "name") String sort)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    //only in case the "sort" query parameter is missing
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public String unsorted(@RequestParam(value = "sort", defaultValue = "name") String name) {
        // do logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the default value for the missing value and continue forward

```
@RequestParam(value = "sort", defaultValue = "name") String name
```